# Composing Promises and non-promise values

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have some code that essentially looks like this:

```
let foos = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
let bars = foos.map(foo => new Promise(resolve => resolve(foo + ' processed')));
function f(foo, bar) { '...' };
```

As you can see, `f()` requires a `foo` and a `bar` argument. The problem is that `bar` is a `Promise`. Had `f()` only required `bar`, I would do:

```
Promise.all(bars).then(values => values.map(f));
```

However, `f()` requires both the `bar` value resulting from the `Promise` and its matching non-promise `foo`, so I'm not sure what's the best way to code this?

Comment: Your `bars` promises are never resolved?

Comment: @Bergi: Whoops, edited.

Answer (score 3):

`.map` passes the index of the element to the callback too, so you could do

```
Promise.all(bars).then(
   values => values.map((value, i) => f(foos[i], value))
);
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but the code above is just a sample. In the actual code, `foos` is not in the scope of the `.then()` handler, so a big part of the problem is to pass the `foo` into that scope.

Comment: That seems to be a very different question then. `foos` needs to be in scope of whatever calls `.then`. I assumed that if `bars` is in scope, `foos` is as well. Please provide a better example of your problem.

Comment: @DunPeal: How would the `foo`s be in scope if `bar` was not a promise?

Answer (score 1):

If `foos` is not in scope of the `Promise.all().then()` handler, then you need to ensure that `foos` as well as `bars` are delivered down the promise chain.

Here's a couple of approaches :

**1. Deliver an array of objects**

Each object will contain a `foo` and its corresponding `bar`.

```
let foos = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
let promises = foos.map(foo => new Promise(resolve => resolve({
    unprocessed: foo,
    processed: foo + ' processed'
})));
// ...
Promise.all(promises).then(results => results.map(obj => f(obj.unprocessed, obj.processed)));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rLjn8y9u/1/)

**2. Deliver an object of arrays**

The object will contain a `foos` array and a congruant `bars` array.

```
let foos = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
let promise = Promise.all(foos.map(foo => new Promise(resolve => resolve(foo + ' processed'))))
    .then(bars => ({ 'unprocessed': foos, 'processed': bars }));
// ...
promise.then(obj => obj.unprocessed.map((foo, i) => f(foo, obj.processed[i])));
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gwwa0y0w/)

(1) is arguably less messy than (2).

Answer (score 0):

(Adhering to the restriction mentioned in comments that `foos` is not in scope...)

You can pass the extra argument down the chain a little smoother using ES6 destructuring:

```
let foos = ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'];
let bars = foos.map(foo => new Promise(res => res([foo, foo + ' processed'])));
Promise.all(bars).then(values => values.map(([foo, bar]) => f(foo, bar)));
```